# How to create lists of various categories of references (or similar) automatically

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to do something that I feel should be possible, but I'm not easily able to find a way to do it.

[This is example is very close to my actual example, but changed to avoid needing esoteric domain knowledge.]
Suppose I have the football rulebook in LaTeX. It has many references to fouls and penalties to go with those fouls. I assume that I can go through and mark up where these penalties are in the body of the text.

I want to add an appendix which lists the various things, categorised by the penalty. So you can go to this appendix and find a "list of fouls by type", which will contain (for Americans) "5-yard penalty fouls"; "10-yard fouls" ; "15-yard fouls" ; "Ejection fouls" ; etc... or (for most of the rest of the world) "indirect free kick fouls" ; "direct free kick fouls" ; "yellow card fouls" ; "red card fouls".

There's a standard way of listing these things in the body of the text, so I already have a macro along the lines of `\tenyardfoul{ describe it here }` and `\redcardfoul{ describe it here }` which I can modify to add hooks to or something. I've some flexibility in how to format these too. I did look at making them tables, and that way I could get a full list via `\listoftables` but splitting it into categories was beyond me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage, in the end, to work something out. It feels a bit like I'm abusing the caption package to do this, so if anyone knows a neater/more idiomatic way to do this I'm all ears (or - given the nature text - all eyes, if you want to be pedantic).

**Current issues**

- Affects all captions globally in a way that's probably undesirable for other projects. (I just happen to get away with it.)
- If you have a lot of lists like this (I have 13) you can run into the "no room for new \write" error. I fixed this with `\usepackage{morewrites}` but I seem to remember seeing a way to fix this within the caption package, but cannot for the life of me find it anymore.

**The actual solution**

I'll keep my football analogy running, and show how I implemented this for yellow cards and 15-yard penalties.

I use these packages. I'm not 100%  sure I need the float package to make this work, but I rely on it elsewhere so I can't easily remove it to test.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
```

First I declare a caption type for each list:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{yellowcardf}
\DeclareCaptionType{fifteenyardpenaltyf}
% etc...
```

The "f" suffix is to avoid name clashes.

When I do the `\listof` command, I actually want to skip adding titles. This is so I can set my own title and add an introductory paragraph. For that reason I do this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
        \expandafter\let\csname l@#1\endcsname \l@figure 
        %\float@listhead{#2}%  <-------------------------- % comment this line out
        \begingroup
        \setlength\parskip{0pt plus 1pt}%  
        \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
        \endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

I set up how I want captions to look like so:

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{1pt}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible to do on a per-caption-type basis (almost certainly) but it's probably a good idea to do it that way on your projects. This affects all captions globally. Fortunately, that doesn't matter for my particular project. Good luck, and hopefully another commentator can fill you in on that.

Now I set up a generic command to use for lists:

```
\newcommand{\genericpenalty}[3] {\begin{#1}[H]
    \caption[\textbf{\thesubsubsection} --- #3]{\textbf{Penalty: #2} --- #3}
\end{#1}}
```

And finally, each list gets its own wrapper:

```
\newcommand{\yellowcard}[1]{\genericpenalty{yellowcardf}{yellow card}{#1}}
\newcommand{\fifteenyardpenalty}[1]{\genericpenalty{redcardf}{red card}{#1}}
```

Now I can write `\yellowcard{unsportsmanlike conduct}` and `\yellowcard{reckless tackle}` or `\fifteenyyardpenalty{chop blocking}` and `\fifteenyardpenalty{grabbing the facemask}` in my document, and it will create a nice little insert for me inline with the text (which I can format nicely too - but I removed all that here as it was largely noise). It will also add it to a list at the end which I create like this:

```
\newcommand{\addlistofpenalties}[3]{\subsection{#2}
    #3
    \listof{#1}{}
}
```

And then:

```
\section{List of offences by penalty}
\subsection{Football (soccer) penalties}
\addlistofpenalties{yellowcardf}{Yellow card penalties}{The referee should caution a player for these offences:}
\subsection{Football (American) penalties)
\addlistofpenalties{fifteenyardpenaltyf}{15-yard penalties}{These penalties move the fouled team 15-yards towards their opponent's end-zone:}
```

This will create a list of penalties using the short caption, which in this case includes the subsubsection reference for easy lookup.

If I have `\usepackage{hyperref}` these turn into clickable hyperlinks as well for free!

I'm sure there's some room for improvement here, but if you're looking for a solution to this problem, feel free to use and adapt this (built using pdflatex on Windows, FWIW, although I believe it should be portable) and if you have improvements let me know and I'll be glad to update this to reflect the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a number to each type of penalty, you can have LaTeX write entries for all penalties into the same auxiliary file and let the `\listof...`-commands do the filtering for you by setting a variable to the number of the type of penalty for which the list is to be created before inputting the auxiliary file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in curly braces>{CsToken}
% yields:
% <stuff not in curly braces>\CsToken
%
% E.g. ,
% \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{foobar}...
% yields:
% \newcommand*\foobar...
%...............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{\long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral0\InnerCsNameToScToken{#1}}}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToScToken[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\penaltytypecount{0}%
\newcommand\steppenaltytypecount{%
  \xdef\penaltytypecount{\number\numexpr\penaltytypecount+1\relax}%
}%

\newif\ifpenaltyitemfound

\newcommand\newpenaltytype[7]{%
  % #1 - name of the penalty type
  % #2 - textual phrase denoting the kind of penalty
  % #3 - formatting of the counter for counting penalites of the type
  % #4 - numbered within-counter
  % #5 - Command for writing the penalty within the main-text
  % #6 - \listof-command
  % #7 - sectioning-command for starting the list of penalites
  \steppenaltytypecount
    % Mapping "name of the penalty type" to automatically created number of penalty type:
  \CsNameToCsToken\@ifdefinable{penaltynum@#1}{\CsNameToCsToken\xdef{penaltynum@#1}{\penaltytypecount}}%
    % Counter for penalties of type #1:
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#4}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\newcounter{#1cnt}}{\newcounter{#1cnt}[{#4}]}%
    % Apply command(s) #3 for formatting the counter:
    \CsNameToCsToken\renewcommand*{the#1cnt}{#3{#1cnt}}%
    % Define the command for writing the penalty within the main-text:
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter#5\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@ifnextchar\expandafter[\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\@firstoftwo{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}{} %
    \romannumeral\CsNameToCsToken0 \expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string#5@opt}%
    \expandafter}%
    \expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\CsNameToCsToken0 {\expandafter\@gobble\string#5@noopt}}%
  }%
  \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{\expandafter\@gobble\string#5@opt}[2][]{%
    % #1 - name of the penalty type
    % #2 - textual phrase denoting the kind of penalty
    % ##1 - short description of penalty
    % ##2 - long description of penalty
    \textbf{\refstepcounter{allpenalties}\refstepcounter{#1cnt}Penalty~}%
    \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{}{\NR@gettitle{#2~\CsNameToCsToken{the#1cnt}}}%
    \addtocontents{lpn}{%
      \string\penaltyitem{#1}%
                         {\CsNameToCsToken{the#1cnt}}%
                         {\thepage}%
                         {\@ifundefined{@currentHref}{}{\@currentHref}}%
                         {#2}%
                         {##1}\protected@file@percent
    }%    
    \textbf{\CsNameToCsToken{the#1cnt}: #2} --- ##2%
  }%
  \CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string#5@noopt}%
                  \expandafter[\expandafter1\expandafter]\expandafter{%
     \romannumeral\CsNameToCsToken0 {\expandafter\@gobble\string#5@opt}[{##1}]{##1}%
  }%
    % Define the \listof...-command:
  \newcommand*#6{%
    #7%
    \AtEndDocument{%
      \@ifundefined{tf@lpn}{%
        \if@filesw
          \newwrite\tf@lpn
          \immediate\openout\tf@lpn\jobname.lpn\relax
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
    \begingroup\makeatletter
    \edef\penaltytypecount{\CsNameToCsToken{penaltynum@#1}}%
    \global\penaltyitemfoundfalse
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.lpn}{%
      \begin{description}%
      \@input{\jobname.lpn}%
      \ifpenaltyitemfound\else\expandafter\item\expandafter\leavevmode\expandafter\null\fi
      \end{description}%
    }{}%
    \@nobreakfalse\endgroup
  }%
}%
\newcommand\listofallpenalties{%
  \subsection*{List of all penalties}%
  \AtEndDocument{%
    \@ifundefined{tf@lpn}{%
      \if@filesw
        \newwrite\tf@lpn
        \immediate\openout\tf@lpn\jobname.lpn\relax
      \fi
    }{}%
  }%
  \begingroup\makeatletter
  \let\penaltyitem\allpenaltyitem
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.lpn}{%
    \begin{description}%
    \@input{\jobname.lpn}%
    \ifpenaltyitemfound\else\expandafter\item\expandafter\leavevmode\expandafter\null\fi
    \end{description}%
  }{}%
  \@nobreakfalse\endgroup
}%
\newcommand\penaltyitem[6]{%
  % #1 name of penalty
  % #2 number of penalty
  % #3 page number where the penalty is described in the text
  % #4 hyperref-anchor if hyperref is loaded
  % #5 textual phrase denoting the kind of penalty
  % #6 (short) description of the penalty
  \ifnum\penaltytypecount=\@ifundefined{penaltynum@#1}{0}{\CsNameToCsToken{penaltynum@#1}} %
  \expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
  {%
    \ifpenaltyitemfound\else\global\penaltyitemfoundtrue\fi
    \item[\@ifundefined{hyperlink}{\@firstofone}{\hyperlink{#4}}{\textbf{#2 (on page~#3):}}] #6%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\allpenaltyitem[6]{%
  % #1 name of penalty
  % #2 number of penalty
  % #3 page number where the penalty is described in the text
  % #4 hyperref-anchor if hyperref is loaded
  % #5 textual phrase denoting the kind of penalty
  % #6 (short) description of the penalty
  \@ifundefined{penaltynum@#1}{}{%
    \ifpenaltyitemfound\else\global\penaltyitemfoundtrue\fi
    \item[\@ifundefined{hyperlink}{\@firstofone}{\hyperlink{#4}}{\textbf{#2 (#5, on page #3):}}] #6%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\newcounter{allpenalties}[section]%
\renewcommand\theallpenalties{\thesection.\arabic{allpenalties}}%

\newpenaltytype{YellowCards}%
               {Yellow Card}%
               {Y\protect~\thesection.\arabic}%  If you wish all penalties to use the same counter, then try: {\theallpenalties\csname @gobble\endcsname}%
               {section}%
               {\YellowCard}%
               {\listofYellowCards}%
               {\subsection*{List of Yellow Card penalties}}

\newpenaltytype{RedCards}%
               {Red Card}%
               {R\protect~\thesection.\arabic}%   If you wish all penalties to use the same counter, then try: {\theallpenalties\csname @gobble\endcsname}%
               {section}%
               {\RedCard}
               {\listofRedCards}%
               {\subsection*{List of Red Card penalties}}

\newpenaltytype{GreenCards}%
               {Green Card}%
               {G\protect~\thesection.\arabic}%   If you wish all penalties to use the same counter, then try: {\theallpenalties\csname @gobble\endcsname}%
               {section}%
               {\GreenCard}
               {\listofGreenCards}%
               {\subsection*{List of Green Card penalties}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Lists of penalties:}

\listofRedCards

\listofYellowCards

\listofGreenCards

\listofallpenalties

\section{First Section}

\noindent\YellowCard[This is the first section's first Yellow Card's short description.]{This is the first section's first Yellow Card's long description.}

\noindent\RedCard[This is the first section's first Red Card's short description.]{This is the first section's first Red Card's long description.}

\noindent\GreenCard[This is the first section's first Green Card's short description.]{This is the first section's first Green Card's long description.}

\noindent\GreenCard{This is the first section's second Green Card's description.}

\noindent\YellowCard{This is the first section's second Yellow Card's description.}

\noindent\RedCard{This is the first section's second Red Card's description.}

\section{Second Section}

\noindent\YellowCard[This is the second section's first Yellow Card's short description.]{This is the second section's first Yellow Card's long description.}

\noindent\RedCard[This is the second section's first Red Card's short description.]{This is the second section's first Red Card's long description.}

\noindent\GreenCard[This is the second section's first Green Card's short description.]{This is the second section's first Green Card's long description.}

\noindent\GreenCard{This is the second section's second Green Card's description.}

\noindent\YellowCard{This is the second section's second Yellow Card's description.}

\noindent\RedCard{This is the second section's second Red Card's description.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]